# Factoring public holidays in to a SQL code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Apologies if this is a simple one. I'm looking for some help with the following:

```
SELECT *                        
FROM (                  
    SELECT TOP 7                
        RIGHT (CONVERT (VARCHAR, CompletedDate, 108), 8) AS Time,           
        WorkType            
            FROM Table      
                WHERE WorkType = 'WorkType1'    
                    OR DATEPART (DW, CompletedDate) IN ('7','1')
                    AND WorkType = 'WorkType2'
    ORDER BY CompletedDate DESC) Table              
ORDER BY CompletedDate ASC
```

Multiple events run every day, and the above searches for the last one scheduled to run each day, and pulls the time from it for the past 7 days. This time marks the end of the day's events, and is the value I'm after.

Events run at a different order on weekends, so I search for a different WorkType. WorkType 1 is unique to weekdays. WorkType2 is run both at weekdays and weekends, however it is not the final event on a weekday, so I don't search for it then.

However, this kind of falls apart when public holidays such as bank holidays come into play, as they use the weekend timings. I still need to capture these times, but the above skips over them. If I were to remove or expand the DATEPART, I would end up with duplicate values for each day that don't mark the final job of the day.

What changes can I make to this to capture these lost holiday timings, without manually going through and checking every holiday? Is there a way that I can return a value for JobType2, if JobType1 does not appear on a day?

Comment: Careful that you have 2 filtering conditions for the `WorkType` column (WorkType1, WorkType2). Due to this a lot of rows will be filtered because both conditions cannot be true at the same time (but you will still have results shown because of your `OR` and in the end the rows that you will see are the ones that validate the `OR` condition). Maybe you are looking for checking if the WorkType column has at least one of those values (in which scenario you should use `EXISTS`) **OR** if the WorkType is both values if they exist, in which scenario you need `WorkType IN ('WorkType1', 'WorkType2')`

Comment: I suggest creating materialized calendar table with one row per date along with WorkType.  You can simply join to the calendar table to determine the WorkType value without embedding the logic in the query itself.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/ for an example of such a table.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a materialized calendar table with one row per date along with the desired WorkType for that day.  That will allow you to simply join on to the calendar table to determine the proper WorkType value without embedding the logic in the query itself.

With this table loaded with all dates for your reporting domain:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WorkTypeCalendar(
      CalendarDate date NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Calendar PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , WorkType varchar(10) NOT NULL
);
GO
```

The query can be refactored as below:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 7
                    RIGHT(CONVERT (varchar, CompletedDate, 108), 8) AS Time
                  , WorkType
          FROM      Table1 AS t
                    JOIN WorkTypeCalendar AS c ON t.WorkType = c.WorkType
                                                  AND t.CompletedDate >= c.CalendarDate
                                                  AND t.CompletedDate < DATEADD(DAY,
                                                              1,
                                                              c.CalendarDate)
          ORDER BY  CompletedDate DESC
        ) Table1
ORDER BY CompletedDate ASC
```

You also might consider making this a generalized utility calendar table.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/ for an complete example of such a table and script to load US holidays you can adjust for your needs and locale.